# SQL function returning a error regarding a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good morning all,

I am trying to make a revenue view, but I am stuck due to a error I cannot fix. 
I've made a function which calcutates total revenue from both Accessories and Bikes. The function combines these to give a result per month, which is the variable. I tried the seperate queries and they seem to work properly. The following occurs, I seem to be missing a step I think:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION fnOmzetPMaand
    (
        @Maand AS int
    )
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @AccOmzet AS int

    SET @AccOmzet = (
    SELECT dbo.fnOmzet(SUM(a.Accessoire_Dagprijs), h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)
    FROM Huurovereenkomst h
        INNER JOIN HuurovereenkomstAccessoire ha
        ON ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Huurovereenkomst_id = h.Huurovereenkomst_id
        INNER JOIN Accessoire a
        ON a.Accessoire_id = ha.HuurovereenkomstAccessoire_Accessoire_id
        WHERE MONTH(h.Huurovereenkomst_Betaal_datum) = @Maand
        GROUP BY h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
        )

    DECLARE @FietsOmzet AS int

    SET @FietsOmzet = (
    SELECT dbo.fnOmzet(SUM(f.Fiets_Dagprijs), h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)
    FROM Huurovereenkomst h
        INNER JOIN HuurovereenkomstFiets hf
        ON hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id = h.Huurovereenkomst_id
        INNER JOIN Fiets f
        ON f.Fiets_id = hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id
        WHERE MONTH(h.Huurovereenkomst_Betaal_datum) = @Maand
        GROUP BY h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum
        )

    RETURN @FietsOmzet + @AccOmzet
    END
```

The view:

```
    CREATE VIEW vOmzetPMaand
    AS
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, Huurovereenkomst_Betaal_datum) Maand,
    dbo.fnOmzetPMaand(MONTH(Huurovereenkomst_Betaal_datum)) Omzet
    FROM Huurovereenkomst
```

The error:

```
    Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
    Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the 
    subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an 
    expression.
```

The expected results:

```
   May  100
   June 200
   July 150
   etc etc.

    USE [Biker]
    GO
    /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnOmzet]    Script Date: 05-Jan-18 12:05:50 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnOmzet]
        (
            @Bedrag AS int,
            @BeginDatum AS DATETIME,
            @EindDatum AS DATETIME
        )
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN

        RETURN @Bedrag * DATEDIFF(Y, @BeginDatum, @EindDatum)

    END
```

Comment: where is the code for fnOmzet ?

Comment: The error message is giving you the answer here: `Subquery returned more than 1 value.`. As for which query, that's a totally different question, but you have 2 sub queries in there, so you'll have to check those. We can't check, as we can't run your code (we don't have access to your Server!).

Comment: Added the fnOmzet, @Larnu I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: @MrEmper you only have 2 sub selects, so start with either of those. If it's not the first one you check, it's the other. (sorry tagged wrong person).

Comment: @LukStorms How do you mean?

Comment: @MrEmper If you SET a variable with a query then it only works if that query only returns 1 row with 1 value. So you just need to modify those queries for `@AccOmzet` and `@FietsOmzet`  so those can't return multiple rows.

Comment: I see, that's a good point there. Still thinking how I could possibly get this going haha

Comment: @MrEmper How about wrapping such query in a select that SUM's the results?

Comment: @LukStorms Is that possible within a function or is it waste of time to do it that way?

Comment: Seems just a quick fix compared to completely rewriting the query. Simplyfied example `declare @v1 int = (select v from (values (1),(2)) q(v))` versus `declare @v int = (select sum(v) from (select v from (values (1),(2)) q1(v)) q2)`

Comment: Btw, normally when querying on dates the year is often included in the search. Because more often the previous years aren't purged automatically from such table.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have two subqueries but both are using the same table and grouped by the same criteria.

Without looking at your dataset, I would said that since the expected result is aggregated by month (based on your question): The impacting data is very likely that you have more than one combination of "h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum" per month. If that is the case, and since those columns values are grouped but not aggregated they would be returning multiple rows.

The following are some of the options that I can think of so far:

Option 1. Use aggregated functions on both of those fields like min and max (if the business logic allows for it in order to obtain a single record.

Option 2. Handling the multiple rows of each result and guarantee a single resultant value. (this can be accomplish with multiple solutions that could be from extra sub query withing your select statement, to even return the values on a table alike structure like table variable and then do an extra processing to return only the final value over the multiple rows)

Option 3. Extract somehow the relevant month from the combination "h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum" and group by the month instead of the you current grouping.

**Important:** I would prefer the option #3 or some variation of it if the business rules allows it.